Disable TLS for particular outgoing domain in postfix
Is there a way we can disable TLS for a particular domain, the global setting for outgoing SMTP is encrypt.
We have an ipsec tunnel to the destination and they dont have TLS enabled at their end.
Postfix server tls settings:
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
The destination is configured in Transport file:
example.com smtp:[10.1.1.100]:25

Implement a policy table via the smtp_tls_policy_maps parameter and configure the TLS exception.
In main.cf:
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/portfix/smtp_tls_policy_maps.cf

in /etc/portfix/smtp_tls_policy_maps.cf:
example.com none

Don't forget to run postmap and then reload Postfix.
